# Fitting to a noisy exponential

Tags: curve, exponential

I'm trying to fit my my noise data to an exponential. It seems that the least squares fit is consistently giving a slower decay time than the data actually suggests. I've tried smoothing the data via convolution with a Gaussian, and that gives a faster decay time than it should! Here is a picture of some data I generated that exemplifies my point:

[image: graph]

The red curve is just an exponential, which I added some gaussian noise to to make the blue curve. The teal curve is the blue curved smoothed with a gaussian kernel. The green is the least squares fit to the teal curve, and the purple is the least squares fit to the blue curve (what I call the actual data). Does anyone know the best way to fit to an exponential to minimize this effect (i.e., what will give the curve which is most similar to the red curve)? Any help or really any ideas at all related to this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might get a better response at either [CrossValidated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or possibly [Mathemtics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), since they both focus explicitly around statistics and math respectively.

Comment: yep, exactly, math.stackexchange.com